# Basic question: what does this mean: polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a root mod $d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What does "A polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a root of mod $d$" mean?

I'm not quite sure what this means, my search has led me to a few slightly different answers. I'd love to see an example.

Would this be correct:

There is some $n$ such that $f(n)$ is congruent to $0 \pmod d$
i.e. $f(n)$ is a multiple of $d$.

Thank you so much

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, assuming $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work looks good to me. An example might be $f(x) = x^{2}+1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. One can see that $f(1) = 1^{2}+1 = 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, so we would say $f$ has a root ($1$) modulo $2$. Another example is $f(x) = x^{3}+8 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Here, we see $f(2) = 16 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$, so $f$ has a root modulo $4$.

In general, as you suggested, $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a root $\pmod d$ if $\exists z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(z)$ is a multiple of $d$.